# Mutually exclusive url encoding between encodeURIComponent and encodeURI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is a problem that is somewhat specific to `react-router`. Let say we have a blog post with an id of: `id%20/something`. This id is **not** encoded.

When navigating to the detail page of the blog post, I want to put the id into the path. The route patters looks like this (this time I'm encoding with `encodeURIComponent`):

`blog/post/id%2520%2Fsomething`

With react router we can access our route parameters with a hook called `useParams`. This function will auto-decode url parameters using `decodeURI` resulting in a parameter value:

`id%20%2Fsomething`

As you can see the `/` was not correctly decoded and is still present as `%2F`. I now ended up with a mix of encoded and decoded values.

I'm looking for the easiest way to arrive at a fully decoded string.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that it used `decodeURI` instead of `decodeURIComponent`. The latter does the correct thing. If you have no control over this choice, this might be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
// check all ASCII codepoints if encodeURI and encodeURIComponent treat them
// differently — non-ASCII are always encoded by both functions
const diffs = Array.from({ length: 0x7f }, (_, i) => String.fromCodePoint(i))
    .filter(x => encodeURI(x) !== encodeURIComponent(x))

const re = new RegExp(diffs.map(encodeURIComponent).join('|'), 'g')

const clean = (x) => x.replace(re, decodeURIComponent)

console.log(re) // => /%23|%24|%26|%2B|%2C|%2F|%3A|%3B|%3D|%3F|%40/g
console.log(clean('id%20%2Fsomething')) // => 'id%20/something'
```

Or, a pre-calculated version:

```js
const clean = (x) => x.replace(
    /%23|%24|%26|%2B|%2C|%2F|%3A|%3B|%3D|%3F|%40/g,
    decodeURIComponent,
)
```